# Setup dual NIC for selective apps to use a VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, syntax

I am relatively new to ubuntu but have learnt a lot while trying to fix my setup.

Basically, my problem is that I have a Desktop computer that needs to connect to a VPN service for certain applications, but I sometimes use it for BBC iPlayer and having any form a VPN limits BBC iPlayer from working.

My plan is to bind certain applications to one NIC and other to the the other. I then can use my ASUSwrt router to manage which NIC is directed to the VPN tunnel and which one is not. That said, I would be happy to hear of other ways to do this is there are better/more elegant options.

So far I have discovered that I need to edit the `/etc/network/interfaces` file. But when I do I get a network failure as both NIC's I have in the machine stop working. The file currently reads:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp6s0 enp9s0

# Ethernet motherboard port
iface enp6s0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.120/24
    network 192.168.1.0
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    metric 50
    up route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 192.168.1.1
    up route add default gw 192.168.1.1

# Ethernet tp-link PCIe port
iface enp9s0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.121/24
    network 192.168.1.0
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    metric 100
```

Clearly the first 3 lines are auto generated.

I have tried a multitude of other variations but without success. Please could someone help me with the right interfaces code. I would appreciate knowing if there is a simple way to use `route` to send application traffic to each NIC too?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Having some connectios via VPN, and some on the clear is against the design philosophy of VPNs, and could open the VPN to attack. BBC seems to be using the VPN check  to restrict access, forbidding non-British clients. Pick one: BBC or VPN.

Comment: Well, I have certainly read that certain port traffic can be routed (or ignored) via the VPN ... so perhaps I can get the right syntax explained for doing this with OpenVPN?

Comment: Anyone? The original question was about getting the interfaces file working so both controllers are working and not causing failures. That would be appreciated...